# Create console in python

Tags: python, console, interactive

I'm looking to have the same functionality (history, ...) as when you simply type python in your terminal. The script I have goes through a bunch of setup code, and when ready, the user should have a command prompt. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the script from the console with `python -i`. It will go through the commands and drop you in the usual Python console when it's done.

Comment: @sharvey - I just found that out myself last week :) Depending on the platform, if you want a desktop launcher you'll need to look up whatever way is necessary to make the terminal program persist.

Answer (score 9):

Either use [`readline`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/readline/) and code the shell behaviour yourself, or simply prepare the environment and drop into [`IPython`](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython).

Comment: Thank for the links, looks promising.

Comment: detly's answer is simpler and fits the problem at hand. Thanks for the info, i'll definitely bookmark that.